# Не запускаются тесты Jest (React)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jest

Сделал `eject` React Create App. Вынес конфиг babel в js файл, отредактировал конфиг jest'а по туторам, но, что бы дальше не менял, получаю ошибку:

> Jest encountered an unexpected token
>
> Details:
>
> C:\Users\Acer\reactnativeweb\test-setup.js:1
>
> ({"Object.":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,
>
> bal,jest){import { configure } from 'enzyme';
>
> ```
>             ^
> ```
>
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

App.unit.test.tsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import App from '../App';

describe('Shallow Render REACT COMPONENTS', () => {
    let wrapper: any;

    beforeEach(()=>{
        wrapper = shallow(<App />)
    })
    
    it('Render App component', () => {
       expect(wrapper.length).toEqual(1)
    });
});
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "react-native-web-example-as-testtask",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.5.5",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.5.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.5.5",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.5.5",
    "@svgr/webpack": "4.3.2",
    "@types/enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.0.5",
    "@types/node": "12.7.2",
    "@types/react": "16.9.1",
    "@types/react-dom": "16.8.5",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.60.5",
    "@types/styled-components": "^4.1.18",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "1.13.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "1.13.0",
    "babel-eslint": "10.0.2",
    "babel-jest": "^24.8.0",
    "babel-loader": "8.0.6",
    "babel-plugin-named-asset-import": "^0.3.3",
    "camelcase": "^5.2.0",
    "case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin": "2.2.0",
    "css-loader": "2.1.1",
    "dotenv": "6.2.0",
    "dotenv-expand": "4.2.0",
    "eslint": "^6.1.0",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^5.0.1",
    "eslint-loader": "2.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "3.13.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.18.2",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.2.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.14.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^1.6.1",
    "file-loader": "3.0.1",
    "fs-extra": "7.0.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "4.0.0-beta.5",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "3.0.0",
    "is-wsl": "^1.1.0",
    "jest-environment-jsdom-fourteen": "0.1.0",
    "jest-resolve": "24.8.0",
    "jest-watch-typeahead": "0.3.1",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "0.5.0",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "5.0.3",
    "pnp-webpack-plugin": "1.5.0",
    "postcss-flexbugs-fixes": "4.1.0",
    "postcss-loader": "3.0.0",
    "postcss-normalize": "7.0.1",
    "postcss-preset-env": "6.7.0",
    "postcss-safe-parser": "4.0.1",
    "react": "^16.9.0",
    "react-app-polyfill": "^1.0.2",
    "react-art": "^16.9.0",
    "react-dev-utils": "^9.0.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "react-native": "^0.60.5",
    "react-native-web": "^0.11.6",
    "resolve": "1.12.0",
    "resolve-url-loader": "3.1.0",
    "sass-loader": "7.2.0",
    "semver": "6.3.0",
    "style-loader": "1.0.0",
    "styled-components": "^4.3.2",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "1.4.1",
    "ts-pnp": "1.1.2",
    "typescript": "^3.5.3",
    "url-loader": "2.1.0",
    "webpack": "4.39.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "3.2.1",
    "webpack-manifest-plugin": "2.0.4",
    "workbox-webpack-plugin": "4.3.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node scripts/start.js",
    "build": "node scripts/build.js",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "@types/enzyme": "^3.10.3",
    "@types/jest": "^24.0.17",
    "babel-preset-react-app": "^9.0.1",
    "enzyme": "^3.10.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.14.0",
    "enzyme-to-json": "^3.4.0",
    "jest": "^24.9.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.9.0",
    "ts-jest": "^24.0.2"
  }
}
```

babel.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
    "presets": [
      "react-app"
    ],
}
```

jest.config.json

```
module.exports = {
    "roots": [
      "<rootDir>/src"
    ],
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(ts|tsx)$": "<rootDir>/test-preprocessor.js"
    },
    "testRegex": "(/__tests__/.*|(\\.|/)(test|spec))\\.tsx?$",
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "ts",
      "tsx",
      "js",
      "jsx",
      "json",
      "node"
    ],
    "snapshotSerializers": ["enzyme-to-json/serializer"],
    "setupFilesAfterEnv": ["<rootDir>/test-shim.js", "<rootDir>/test-setup.js"]
}
```

Такая ошибка уже не на первом проекте, к сожалению.

UPD:
test-preprocessor.js:

```
/**
 * Transpiles TypeScript to JavaScript code.
 *
 * @link https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/master/examples/typescript/preprocessor.js
 * @copyright 2004-present Facebook. All Rights Reserved.
 */
const tsc = require('typescript');
const tsConfig = require('./tsconfig.json');

module.exports = {
    process(src, path) {
        if (path.endsWith('.ts') || path.endsWith('.tsx') || path.endsWith('.js')) {
            return tsc.transpile(src, tsConfig.compilerOptions, path, []);
        }
        return src;
    },
};
```

test-shim.js:

```
/**
 * Get rids of the missing requestAnimationFrame polyfill warning.
 * 
 * @link https://reactjs.org/docs/javascript-environment-requirements.html
 * @copyright 2004-present Facebook. All Rights Reserved.
 */
global.requestAnimationFrame = function(callback) {
    setTimeout(callback, 0);
};
```

test-setup.js:

```
import { configure } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });
```

Comment: Зачем eject? тесты как названы и в какой папке?

Comment: eject для изменения конфига babel.

Comment: react-native-web-example-as-testtask\src\__tests__\App.test.tsx

Comment: Что у вас в файле `test-preprocessor.js`? Видимо транспайлинга не происходит, поэтому и ругается.

Comment: Обновил, добавив код файлов.

Comment: Подозреваю что `babel.config.json` не подхватывается. Попробуйте переименовать его в `babel.config.js`. И ради интереса попробуйте в `babel.config.js` сделать `console.log` и запустить тесты. Чтоб убедиться что jest всё-таки его видит.

Comment: Было `babel.config.js`, console.log не выводится.

Comment: Если у вас есть шаги для воспроизведения - eject, вынос конфига babel, редактирование конфига jest - то стоит пройти по ним по шагам, и просто посмотреть, на каком шаге поломается.В чистом CRA ведь все работает.